# Moving object and changing opacity on button onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to achieve a thing that when i push a button, another box with quotes should appear at screen and the button should dissapear.

Here is the Script, Html and CSS:

But when i push the button, nothing happens... Any Idéas?

Edit: 
Is it possible to do this with JavaScript instead of jQuery?

Comment: the code is missing ;)

Comment: It won't let me upload the link to jsfiddle

Comment: Here is the [JSFiddle link anyway](http://jsfiddle.net/62ucA/), somehow stackoverflow gives me an error when i try to add a link to another website where i post the code

Comment: I tried the link and it worked for me - after I selected "jQuery" in the extensions & frameworks dropdown (top left).

Comment: Also, stackoverflow doesn't allow adding links to JSFiddle without the code. So, next time you want to share something taht you've written using JSFiddle, add a copy of the code to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#quoteButton').on('click', function() {
    $('#quoteLines').show('fast');
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

and the css for this would be only a display none on your #quoteLines...

In this way, when you click on that button, it shows the quotes, and disappears with the button :)

you could also use fadeIn() instead of show, so it can look more fancy.

-- EDIT

here is the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/62ucA/2/

Comment: Lol, i think that the site is overloaded with javascript now because it still won't to do anything when i press the button.

Comment: This is great! Firefox gives me this error: 

ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: are you trying on this link? http://jsfiddle.net/62ucA/2/

because here is working just fine...

Comment: you have to load jQuery before you use this code... put this before your script <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>

Comment: "you have to load jQuery before you use this code... put this before your script <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>;" i'm sorry but none of the code i used or tried works because of this error [Firefox Error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b8by6u5isfyiods/FirefoxError.png) and the script linking is 404 error not found

Comment: try this from google's CDN <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>